# Animating wires attached to a head

Tags: animation, bones

Alright, so I'm decently new to blender (only about 130~ hours in engine) and I'm trying to... animate? Some wires, specifically.

[image: "Head" with wires]

I'm trying to have one end of the wires stick to the head while it looks around, and the other ends stay put. At first, I just had the first bone in the wire hooked up to the Head bone, which of course causes the entire wire to move when the head moves.

Now I have the end I want to stay still parented to no bone, which.. kinda works, but the wire model stretches quite a bit.

[image: Looking Left]

Looking left, the stretching is hardly noticeable, which is perfect for me. However...

[image: Looking Right]

When looking to the right, it stretches like this. Would there be a way to keep the shape of the wire? IE; locking the tail in place and allowing the head to move around? Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Also, something somewhat related, I want some of the loose wires shown below to wiggle when the head moves. Anyway to do that beyond downloading an addon? Or would that just make the entire experience easier?

[image: Loose Wires]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90694/shaping-bezier-objects-and-applying-physics-collisions

Comment: Did you try IK?

Comment: I recommend a soft body simulation with a curve. Might not be very stable, but could make things much simpler.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242347/bending-wires-like-using-move-with-auto-ik-in-response-to-another-bone-rotation/242351#242351